# How to avoid scroll jump during loading new items to list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chat

I am developing a chat and now I am dealing with the functionality of loading old messages.
When the user has scrolled to the beginning, I request a new block of messages and insert it at the top of the list, then calculate how much space this new block took up and scroll down by this value.
And during this process, you can notice a short jump of the scroll. How can it be avoided?

[demo is here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBcGkjgnazk&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=EugeneDerevyanko)

Comment: Can you share your code? It is pretty hard to figure out what is going on only by looking at a youtube video.

Comment: It's hard to check without code, this is probably because of re-rendering, but why are you calculating block size? It is unnecessary IMO. Check this example https://chatscope.io/storybook/react/?path=/story/components-messagelist--loading-more-state   there is no calculation and it works as expected